# Split HTML (or XML) node text by tags

Tags: html, xml, regex

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div>
Bla bla bla <b>bold stuff</b> Bla bla.
But somewhere else the words bold stuff may appear not in bold
</div>
```

I would like to parse this text to extract the bold elements, and the non-bolded elements as separate lists:

```
bolds = ['bold stuff']
normal_test = [
    'Bla bla bla ', 
    'Bla bla.\nBut somewhere else the words bold stuff may appear not in bold'
]
```

I may be being stupid, but I can't figure out how to do this using "standard" html parsers.

I can extract the full text of the element, including bolds, and i can extract the bolds, but i'm finding it impossible to figure out what the text before and after each bold is, because of the problem of possible dupe non-bold strings.

I'm using lxml, but willing to consider solutions with other parsers, or any clever xpath selectors i don't know about...

But, otherwise, I'm about to resort to regular expressions... Which, as we all know, will be [the end of the world](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/366221)

Can someone save the Earth before it's too late?

Comment: [This can be tough, but possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Answer (score 1):

So I thought this was impossible, but it turns out that if you use the right library, it's not too hard.

With BeautifulSoup 4, you'd use the [.children](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) attribute:

```py
html = '''<div>
Bla bla bla <b>bold stuff</b> Bla bla.
But somewhere else the words bold stuff may appear not in bold
</div>'''
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
print(list(soup.div.children))
[u'\nBla bla bla ',
 <b>bold stuff</b>,
 u' Bla bla.\nBut somewhere else the words bold stuff may appear not in bold\n']
```

And from that it's fairly trivial to achieve what I want.

I'd still be interested if anyone can do it with lxml?